# Extract child node value using SQL QUERY

Tags: sql, sql-server, sqlxml

I have XML in SQL, I want the below result from the query.

| TabSeq | Path | SubTabSeq |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | //Tab/Family | 1 |
| 1 | //Tab/Location | 2 |
| 2 | //Tab/Address | 1 |
| 2 | //Tab/Insurance | 2 |

Below is the XML.

```
<Tabs>
    <Tab sequence="001">
        <Family sequence="001">
            <Data>Yes</Data>
        </Family>
        <Location sequence="002">
            <Data>USA</Data>
        </Location>
    </Tab>
    <Tab sequence="002">
        <Address sequence="001">
            <Data>XYZ</Data>
        </Address>
        <Insurance sequence="002">
            <Data>Yes</Data>
        </Insurance>
    </Tab>
</Tabs>
```

I have tried below,

```
declare @xml xml='<Tabs><Tab sequence="001"><Family sequence="001"><Data>Yes</Data></Family><Location sequence="002"><Data>USA</Data></Location></Tab><Tab sequence="002"><Address sequence="001"><Data>XYZ</Data></Address><Insurance sequence="002"><Data>Yes</Data></Insurance></Tab></Tabs>'

SELECT  t.c.value('@sequence', 'nvarchar(100)') As TabSeq
FROM @xml.nodes('//Tabs/child::node()') as t(c)

SELECT '//Tab' + '/' + c.value('local-name(.)[1]','nvarchar(100)') AS Path,  t.c.value('@sequence', 'nvarchar(100)') As SubTabSeq
FROM @xml.nodes('//Tab/child::node()') as t(c)
```

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your second query you're iteraing subtabs, so you need to reference a parent of those nodes, which is Tab. Like with those two methods (depends on how strict you want to be):

```
SELECT 
  TabSeq1 = t.c.value('../@sequence', 'nvarchar(100)'),
  TabSeq2 = t.c.value('./parent::Tab/@sequence', 'nvarchar(100)'),
  '//Tab' + '/' + c.value('local-name(.)[1]','nvarchar(100)') AS Path,  
  t.c.value('@sequence', 'nvarchar(100)') As SubTabSeq
FROM @xml.nodes('//Tab/child::node()') as t(c)
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following solution.

**SQL**

```
declare @xml XML = 
N'<Tabs>
    <Tab sequence="001">
        <Family sequence="001">
            <Data>Yes</Data>
        </Family>
        <Location sequence="002">
            <Data>USA</Data>
        </Location>
    </Tab>
    <Tab sequence="002">
        <Address sequence="001">
            <Data>XYZ</Data>
        </Address>
        <Insurance sequence="002">
            <Data>Yes</Data>
        </Insurance>
    </Tab>
</Tabs>';

SELECT c.value('for $i in . return count(../../*[. << $i])', 'INT') AS [TabSeq]
    , '//Tab/' + c.value('local-name(.)','nvarchar(100)') AS Path
    ,  t.c.value('@sequence', 'INT') As SubTabSeq
FROM @xml.nodes('/Tabs/Tab/*') as t(c);
```

**Output**

| TabSeq | Path | SubTabSeq |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | //Tab/Family | 1 |
| 1 | //Tab/Location | 2 |
| 2 | //Tab/Address | 1 |
| 2 | //Tab/Insurance | 2 |

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned, you are getting the wrong `sequence` attribute.

You can feed the result of one `.nodes` call into another using `CROSS APPLY`, so you can first shred the `Tab` nodes, then the child nodes

```sql
declare @xml xml='<Tabs><Tab sequence="001"><Family sequence="001"><Data>Yes</Data></Family><Location sequence="002"><Data>USA</Data></Location></Tab><Tab sequence="002"><Address sequence="001"><Data>XYZ</Data></Address><Insurance sequence="002"><Data>Yes</Data></Insurance></Tab></Tabs>'

SELECT 
  TabSeq1 = t2.child.value('@sequence', 'nvarchar(100)'),
  TabSeq2 = t1.tab.value('@sequence', 'nvarchar(100)'),
  Path = '/Tabs/Tab/' + t2.child.value('local-name(.)','nvarchar(100)'),
  Data = t2.child.value('(Data/text())[1]', 'nvarchar(100)')
FROM @xml.nodes('/Tabs/Tab') t1(tab)
CROSS APPLY t1.tab.nodes('*') as t2(child)
```

[**db<>fiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/tmhYpCC-)

Note that `//` descendant axis is slow, you should instead use the `/` child axis.